# I am looking for laser cut cads for my prusa i3?

Tags: prusa-i3, cad

I have this prusa i3 printer(I don't know what model is it):

[image]

My bed part is broken. And I am looking for the cads to laser cut them! this is my bed pic:

[image]

Comment: Information about the printer maker/model is crucial. Yours looks like Hephestos 2, so you can try looking [here](https://github.com/bq/hephestos-2).

Comment: The easiest solution would be to have a copy made from the original part using a router. Any woodworking shop would be able to do that.

Comment: Your plate support is easy to draw; take a picture from above 90°, and redraw in your favorite cad program. This could be drawn in 30 minutes maximum.

Comment: Drawing things using photo alone usually has side effects like millimeter-range projection offsets of the features. Tiny offset of a screw hole - and you will not be able to mount your plate without frustrating adaptations. If you have a part at hand, then better do precise measurements using calipers, it will pay off during assembly stage.

Comment: @ZuOverture: I found a part with exectly that size(although design is a little difference), but the holes are same. I will put it's photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly my part, but the holes place are true. I think if someone measures the bed dimensions( for me it's 21.9mm * 21.9mm) and orders a plate in this size, he can also make holes later with drill(I did it before for another part of my plexi to attach the power supply).

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1310778

[image]